# universal app using cocos2d and a single set of HD images

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a turn-based application which I would like to make universal.  I have a set of HD images (backgrounds & sprites) optimised for iPad retina display.  Can anyone tell me how I can use this single set of images for the various form factors?

For example, how do I show a background (scaled to 90% on y-axis to allow for iAd) on the various form factors?

I am not too concerned about performance nor the difference in iPad/iphone screen ratio.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Do stretchable images. You can use the [`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: (same docs).

2) One very underestimated method is [`+[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
With that method you can fill `UIView`'s with pattern images. Just by setting the `view.backgroundColor`. Or fill a UILabel (textColor) with a shadow like image. Very powerful.